# Rate moblie application using 5 stars in xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin

I need to rate my application based on users view. How can I use the XAML page to do this task. When the reviews are changed `color` of the stars should be changed. (Five) 5 stars are the indicator of the rating.

Answer (score 0):

I found the the solution for this question.here is my solution
Rate your application using 5 stars

I wanted to show the ratings of the application by using the colored stars.
The stars' color should be changed based on the reviews of application.I have tried a lot of to solve this problem by using xaml.finally I found a solution as this xaml.
here is my xaml page.

```
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0">
                        <AbsoluteLayout  BackgroundColor="Gray" 
                                         WidthRequest="142" 
                                         Margin ="0,0,0,535">
                            <StackLayout WidthRequest="{Binding RatingWidth}" 
                                         HeightRequest="30" 
                                         BackgroundColor="Black">  
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Image Source="ratingTransparent.png" 
                                   Aspect="AspectFit" 
                                   BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,AutoSize,AutoSize"
                                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
                            </Image>
                        </AbsoluteLayout>  
                </StackLayout>
```

By setting the StackLayout width I could show the colored stars based on the reviews.Not only I used a Test class to set ehis width of the stacklayoout.
 public  class Test
    {

```
   int Ratings = 10;

    public int RatingWidth
    {
        get
        {
            int y = (143 * Ratings) / 100;
            return y;
        }
    }
}
```

I have implemented this according to the MVVM architecture.this test class has been appered on the Model.
I have given a fixed rating to the ratins.but it can be changed by using getters and stters according to your requirement.
here is my test project for the problem. https://github.com/nayani21/ratings_counter